# How to make background(color, not img) responsive?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building responsive page. One section has a problem. When I make screen smaller background-color goes out(down on few mm).I checked - when I don't have any background - I don't have a problem. How to fix it? Why does it happen?

```css
.bottomright{
 grid-area: bottomright;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;  
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
 position: relative;  
}
.bottomright:hover{ 
 z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 24px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 transform: scale(1.02);
}
.bottomright h4{
 color: #808080; 
 flex: 0 0 auto; 
 align-self: flex-start;
 position: absolute;
 top:2rem;
 left: 2rem;
}
.bottomright img{
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 align-self:center; 
 max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="bottomright">
                <h4>SHCEDULE A MEETING AT
                    <p>IBC 2016</h4>
                <img src="comigo/other/img-event-IBC.jpg">
            </div>
```

Comment: do you have a meta tag in your header?  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"also that's not enough code, post everything

Comment: what do you mean "When I make screen smaller "?
if you are using scaling in your browser - the browser will show you some bugs with rendering in scale mode but not the true problem with your page.
Remember - to check only with 100% scale in any browser.

Comment: please provide a url for an image.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you want responsive you put in a div and then you have to set media screen propperty's for each display device in your css.

Like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    .responsive{
        ...
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1024px){
    .responsive{
        ...
    }
}

/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 980px){
    .responsive{
        ...
    }
}

/* Mobile HD */
@media screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 760px){
    .responsive{
        ...
    }
}

/* Mobile LD */
@media screen and (max-width: 350px){
    .responsive{
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioned  responsive web page but I can't find any media queries in your code. You have to use media queries, only then can you get a responsive web page.

It should like this

```
/* for Mobile */
@media only screen(min-width:630px)
     { ........}

/*for desktop */
@midea only screen (min-width:1224px)
{ .......}
```